# Mapping two complicated entities like a one

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

There is complicated object, mongodb saves it as one object. I tried create same relations in JPA and Hibernate. `javax.persistence` has `@Emeded` and `@Embadable`, but they not worked with List within `SynonymGroup`. Then need map separated tables.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BASE_SYNONYM")  
public class BaseSynonym {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "WORD_ID")
    private String word;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "BASE_SYNONYM_SYNONYM_GROUP",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "WORD_ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DESCRIPTION_ID")
    )
    private List<SynonymGroup> synonymGroup;
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "SYNONYM_GROUP")
public class SynonymGroup {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION_ID")
    private String description;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable
    private List<String> words;
}
```

[image: BaseSynonym object]

I think it's wrong mapping.
Exception:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    root cause

    org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:154)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:57)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:44)
        org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
        org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.saveAll(Unknown Source)
        simple_spring_mvc_project.controller.SynonymController.getAll(SynonymController.java:46)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

root cause

org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:154)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:57)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:44)
    org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.saveAll(Unknown Source)
    simple_spring_mvc_project.controller.SynonymController.getAll(SynonymController.java:46)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$1.convert(MySQLDialect.java:447)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    simple_spring_mvc_project.dao.impl.BaseSynonymDaoImpl.lambda$saveAll$0(BaseSynonymDaoImpl.java:50)
    java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    simple_spring_mvc_project.dao.impl.BaseSynonymDaoImpl.saveAll(BaseSynonymDaoImpl.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.saveAll(Unknown Source)
    simple_spring_mvc_project.controller.SynonymController.getAll(SynonymController.java:46)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4208)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4140)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2597)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2826)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    simple_spring_mvc_project.dao.impl.BaseSynonymDaoImpl.lambda$saveAll$0(BaseSynonymDaoImpl.java:50)
    java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    simple_spring_mvc_project.dao.impl.BaseSynonymDaoImpl.saveAll(BaseSynonymDaoImpl.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.saveAll(Unknown Source)
    simple_spring_mvc_project.controller.SynonymController.getAll(SynonymController.java:46)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: why not post the root cause exception? the one that tells you the problem ...

Comment: plz include the rest of the stacktrace. The root cause of the exception is not present on the snipped you pasted

Comment: sorry, full log added. Information seemed to be non-talking about